# mongo query from loopback issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I am trying to query in mongo db from loopback model. But i am not getting any result from monogdb

This is how my document looks like in mongodb

```
{"_id":"5b9f8bc51fbd7f248cabe742",
"agentType":"Online-Shopping",
"projectId":"modroid-server",
"labels":["category","price"],
"phrases":["Look for _^ct_ in _^p_ ",
"I need _^ct_ in _^p_",
"can you search for _^ct_ in _^p_"]
}
```

here is my datasource file

```
{
"db": {
"name": "db",
"connector": "memory"
},
"modroid-server": {
"host": "localhost",
"port": 27017,
"url": "",
"database": "modroid-server",
"password": "",
"name": "modroid-server",
"user": "",
"connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

and here  is model-config file

```
{
"_meta": {
"sources": [
  "loopback/common/models",
  "loopback/server/models",
  "../common/models",
  "./models"
],
"mixins": [
  "loopback/common/mixins",
  "loopback/server/mixins",
  "../common/mixins",
  "./mixins"
]
},
"User": {
"dataSource": "db"
},
"AccessToken": {
"dataSource": "db",
"public": false
},
"ACL": {
"dataSource": "db",
"public": false
},
"RoleMapping": {
"dataSource": "db",
"public": false,
"options": {
  "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
}
},
 "Role": {
"dataSource": "db",
"public": false
 },
"agent": {
"dataSource": "modroid-server",  // here is my mongodb
"public": true
 }
}
```

and here is my code to query in mongodb

```
module.exports = function (Agent) {
Agent.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection("text-responses");
        collection.find({ "where": { "labels":  ["category", "price"]  } }, function (err, res) { // define whichever query you need
            console.log("collection find res:"+res);
            console.log("collection find err:"+err);

            if(err) {
            cb(err);
            return;
          }
          res.toArray(function (err, realRes) { // this part is crucial
          // otherwise if you try to print res you will get a dump of the db object
            if(err) {
              cb(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log("documnet result:"+realRes);
            console.log("document err:"+err);
          })
      })
    }
    );
}
```

and when i hit that rest api. I get this output

```
collection find res:[object Object]
collection find err:null
documnet result:
document err:null
```

please help me where i am doing thing wrong. I am stuck in that from couples of days.

**Edited**

when i just print **res** it gives me huge data which starts as

```
Cursor {
pool: null,
server: null,
disconnectHandler:
Store {
 s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
 length: [Getter] },
bson: BSON {},
ns: 'modroid-server.text-responses',
cmd:
{ find: 'modroid-server.text-responses',
 limit: 0,
 skip: 0,
 query: { where: [Object] },
 slaveOk: true,
 readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined } },
```

Comment: can you please check what you get in [object Object] by console.log("collection find res:"+ JSON.stringify(res));

Comment: i get this exception when i do so `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: or please do console.log(res), so exactly know what you get

Comment: it is printing huge json. Please check i have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

**Look like `text-responses` is Not a model.**

**Try with Direct Model Agent.**

```
module.exports = function (Model) {
  Model.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
   Model.find({ "where": { "labels":  ["category", "price"]  } }, function (err, res) { // define whichever query you need
         console.log("collection find res:"+res);
            console.log("collection find err:"+err);
      })
     });
    }
```

**Or 
By collection**

```
module.exports = function (Model) {
Model.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection("collection-name"); //use agent
        collection.find({ "where": { "labels":  ["category", "price"]  } }, function (err, res) { // define whichever query you need
            console.log("collection find res:"+res);
            console.log("collection find err:"+err);
      })
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: actually i have three different collection in my database. And **text-responses** is one of them. How can i query in different collection ? And does model name should be exactly same as collection in mongodb?

Comment: i am not sure, For mapping we need to use as same.

Comment: **db.collection("Agent")** here **Agent** is not the collection name it is my database name?. How can i query in different collection in a single database ?

Comment: You are doing wrong, Use `Model` instead of a database.

Comment: Even changing db.collection to model name is not working for me

Comment: see i am using collection name only... Then also  it is not giving me result. As you can see in my question